# Ruby has_many without destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, reference, foreign-key-relationship

I'm facing a model problem. I've 3 models : User, Address and Residence

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid

  has_one :address, dependent: :destroy #should be has_many but not current problem
  has_many :objects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :residences, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Address

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid

  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :address
  belongs_to :residence, inverse_of: :address

  validates :user, presence: true
```

end

Residence:

```
class Residence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_one :address, through: :user, dependent: :nullify
  has_many :objects, through: :user
end
```

The problem is when I want to delete a User or a Residence The system failed to delete residence due to a foreign key and the system said to me that cannot be done because still reference to residence in adresses table.

I don't want to delete address linked to Residence when I delete residence, address should only be delete bu user deletion (that's why i try to use `nullify` without luck.

Need I to use a join table instead of references between residences and addresses?

Thanks

Comment: There is problem with the way you are setting association. There should not be direct association between `Address` and `User`. You can access `Address` via Residence. So add an association for `User` and `Address` using `has_many_through` on residence.

Comment: There could be a problem because for current `User` they have only one `Address` accessible threw themselves . The new model (with `Residence`) is made that no `User` will exist without less than one `Residence` so with your idea with at least one `Address`, I need to redraw the creation/update of Address for users of previous version to let them use Address. What do you think about a Join table between `Address`and `Residence` ? My idea (I'm not an expert) is that table could let user own Addresses and Residence can be linked to one with this table, no?